# Changing color of drawable in selector

Tags: android, drawable

Is it possible change a color of `drawable` from selector?

My selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_plus_circle_grey600_48dp" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_plus_circle_black_48dp"/>
</selector>
```

I try use that way, (in this case I'm using a selector on tint) but I'm getting some error:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/btAdd"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_circle_black_48dp"
     android:tint="@color/blue_android_focused"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

This is the selector of tint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/blue_android_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/green" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using tint on bitmap (** API 21+**):

Selector: *drawable/selector_add*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_circle_grey600_48dp"
            android:tint="@color/blue_android_pressed" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_circle_grey600_48dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

In the `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_add"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Comment: on xml of selector give this error "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix" on  name="android:drawable", and whem o run give erro on inflate activity with use this selector

Comment: This the sample project I've used, you can try it here, https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5jexf0u1z5jw8i4/AABHy7gKUOBMiAPXrs6i7G0Ba?dl=0

Comment: this only works if drawable is a png, not when it is XML.

Answer (score -2):

You can have the same drawables with different colors, that´s work for me

[image]

Comment: its a image, i dont wanna create one image for each color i want

Comment: So do you want to change the color of a drawable image by selector?

Comment: yes, like this 
                    <ImageView
                        android:tint="@color/blue_android_pressed"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_circle_black_48dp"> but using selector

Answer (score -2):

Your should use tint like this :

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/activity_register_et_fullname"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg_page"
app:backgroundTint="@color/blue_android_focused"/>
```

Use `ImageView` in `AppCompatActivity`, it will be inflated with `AppCompatImageView` (see also `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater`). You should look at the code in it.